# AngularJS merging resources with domain objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, merge, angularjs-resource

I have a domain model for our new JavaScript application.

It is designed to be used against any framework; not specific to AngularJS.

However when I try and incorporate it into my application I am finding it difficult to populate using $resources. I would like to define an AngularJS service with the resource inside it. The service would then merge the resource and the domain model object and provide the output to the controller.

This explains it better: http://plnkr.co/edit/mCCY7rGbCrCS3Z9vR974?p=preview

Ideally I would like `angular.merge(dst, src)` to be a thing but it doesn't exist.

Comment: angular.extend?http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: I agree with @Chandermani take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40628/angularjs-extends-service

Comment: `extend` was my first port of call but it seems that it is having issues with merging the `$resource`. If I replace `$resource` with an extremely simple object the merging just works. Could you have a play with the Plunker and see if I am using extends wrong?!

Comment: only own properties are copied https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7a78aed1603ca7f60f2f70ba27f0102e08862550/src/Angular.js#L195

Comment: all in all you can throw away $resource and build your resource ^^